# Playing with video.js ustream m3u8 file streaming

Tags: javascript, html, streaming, video.js, m3u8

I have tried to play in a web page a m3u8 file streaming with video.js, But I could not do it, I do not know where the mistake is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Video</title>

  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
 <script src="https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-media-sources/releases/download/v0.1.0/videojs-media-sources.js"></script>
  <script src="https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/releases/download/v0.11.2/videojs.hls.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Video</h1>

  <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268" 
  data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/3064708/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8" type='video/mp4'>
  </video>

  <script>
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 20):

Instead of `type='video/mp4'` you need `type='application/x-mpegURL'`.

Check also if cross-domain requests are allowed (CORS).

> **Hosting Considerations**
>
> Unlike a native HLS implementation, the HLS tech has to comply with
>   the browser's security policies. That means that all the files that
>   make up the stream must be served from the same domain as the page
>   hosting the video player or from a server that has appropriate CORS
>   headers configured. Easy instructions are available for popular
>   webservers and most CDNs should have no trouble turning CORS on for
>   your account.

Source: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls

CORS How-To: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: I have placed also type='application/x-mpegURL but don't work. How to check if cross domain is allowed? i thinking that cross domain is only for flash player ....also for html player?

Comment: video.js offers a Flash fallback (video-js.swf) so you might need to add a `crossdomain.xml` on the server. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: I'm trying on jsfiddle i have added some libraries that i have founfd in this example:https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/blob/master/example.html  this is my demo: https://jsfiddle.net/066hfjge/5/

Comment: I tried your original code with my own stream and it worked. Using the ustream.tv source results in a **CORS** error (Access-Control-Allow-Origin). I'll update the answer with instructions.

Comment: ah ok but  i can't acces to ustream server in wich i must insert <FilesMatch "\.(rss)$">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>  therefore is impossible .... with ustream

Answer (score 4):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Video</title>

  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
 <script src="https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-media-sources/releases/download/v0.1.0/videojs-media-sources.js"></script>
  <script src="https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/releases/download/v0.11.2/videojs.hls.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Video</h1>

  <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268" 
  data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="http://iphone-streaming.ustream.tv/uhls/3064708/streams/live/iphone/playlist.m3u8" type='application/x-mpegURL'>
  </video>

  <script>
  var player = videojs('my_video_1');
  </script>

</body>
</html>

<!-- Replace current .m3u8 and check..current file has access issue-->
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Videojs player need to be initialized... therefore I added last segemnt of script in body tag

Comment: Thanks buddy. It was really helpful :) 
Can you kindly tell, what's the problem with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924975/hls-video-not-visible-on-chrome-video-js

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video Player Example</title>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.14.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.14.3/video.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup='{"fluid": true}'>
      <source src="https://live-edge01.telecentro.net.ar/live/smil:tlx.smil/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
    </video>
    <script>
      var player = videojs('my-video');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just replace the link with yours

```
  <source src="https://live-edge01.telecentro.net.ar/live/smil:tlx.smil/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
```

But this one was working at the time of publication.

Answer (score 2):

I found two of the most powerful hls library for video js

**1.videojs-http-streaming**

This library has been generated from **videojs-contrib-hls** Based on the following description

> Notice: this project will be deprecated and is succeeded by videojs-http-streaming. VHS supports HLS and DASH and is built into video.js 7, see the video.js 7 blog post

The short description of `videojs-http-streaming` library is as follows

> Play HLS, DASH, and future HTTP streaming protocols with video.js, even where they're not natively supported.
>   Included in video.js 7 by default!.

Github link: https://github.com/yanwsh/videojs-panorama

**2.videojs-hlsjs-plugin**

The short description of this library is as follows

> Adds HLS playback support to video.js 5.0+ using hls.js library.

The library's strength in using it from the **hls.js** library

videojs-hlsjs-plugin github link : https://github.com/streamroot/videojs-hlsjs-plugin

hls.js github link : https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/

**conclusion**

I used projects from both of these libraries and my experience in using them is that `videojs-hlsjs-plugin` library is due to using a powerful `hls.js` library can be a great option for large projects.